# How can I see who looks at my private group posts again?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

As the administrator of a Private group, I once was able to see who looked at the Facebook posts but now cannot. It is a private group and has never had over 9 members.

How can I see who looks at my private group posts again?

Comment: @Blindspots What detail is missing? I think someone who knows Facebook would be able to answer this question with no issues. (In fact, I'd say I have half of a good answer to this question despite not being an expert at all.) Admittedly, some of this may be due to the recent edits to the post.